# How to make things go through Media channel?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, audio

So, with my Galaxy s3 (version 4.4.2), I have a Life Proof case. It distorts my sound, but only my calls. Anything going through the media channel is fine, so I can listen to music or tv shows with no problem. Is there a way I can make my calls use a different sound channel so they don't get distorted? If not, is there a reason why the media channel isn't distorted but the calls are?